# How working I18nextProvider, withNamespaces in in react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using to react-i18next in my application with `I18nextProvider` and `withNamespaces`.

```js
export const App = () => (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <App />
    </I18nextProvider>
);
```

```js
export default withNamespaces()(ChildComponentOfApp);
```

but I don't understand about relationship of `I18nextProvider` and `withNamespaces`. they do not passing props like `t` function

> The provider is responsible to pass the i18next instance passed in by props down to all the withNamespaces hocs or NamespacesConsumer render prop using react context api.

Is why work? is this render props something in `withNamespaces`?

I know that `withNamespaces` is HOC, but confused this relationship between `I18nextProvider` and `withNamespaces` even after read react-i18next source code.

- [I18nextProvider](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/v9.x.x/src/I18nextProvider.js)
- [withNamespaces](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/v9.x.x/src/withNamespaces.js)

can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I18nextProvider -> you pass in a prop "i18n" containing the i18next instance to use -> the Provider passes it down the JSX tree using context API of react

withNamespaces -> gets the i18n instance from context and passes a t function to your component.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jamuhl!! I understand much better than before.
Okay, my next step is check the JSX tree using context API of react in official document